# c# datetime with microseconds propper format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a date with microseconds, it is calculated by adding ticks from 2000.1.1 basically it works and it looks like:

```
ulong timestampInTicks = ExtendedTimestamp * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 10;
var startDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
string dateWithMicroseconds =  startDate.AddTicks((long)timestampInTicks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
```

Problem is with return format, it returns me something like 19:34:34:260100 so miliseconds and microseconds are combined when i try HH:mm:ss.fff:fff I am getting 19:34:34:260:260 so milliseconds are doubled. Is there a way, except for using splitting string, for doing this??

Comment: I've never seen a format which splits "milliseconds" and "microseconds within a millisecond". The format with values like "19:34:34:260100" is *much* more common. What's expecting "19:34:34:260:100"?

Comment: Looks like you need some custom code for it as it is not supported in the box. Simplest would be to split the milliseconds into 2 halves(0 to 2, and 3 to 5) and display them by separating them with a colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest custom implementation I could think of..

```
ulong ExtendedTimestamp = 99;
ulong timeStampInTicks = ExtendedTimestamp * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 10;
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
string dateWithMicroseconds = startDate.AddTicks((long)timeStampInTicks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
string dateHHmmss = dateWithMicroseconds.Split('.')[0];
string timeffffff = dateWithMicroseconds.Split('.')[1];
int precision = 3;
string milliSecs = timeffffff.Substring(0, precision);
string microSecs = timeffffff.Substring(precision, timeffffff.Length - precision);

string customFormat = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", dateHHmmss, milliSecs, microSecs);
```

Answer (score 1):

since the microsecond is millisecond/1000, so as in reference to this date the format will return 01.01.2008 00:30:45.125.125000. Milliseconds: 125, Microseconds:125000

```
DateTime dates =  new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 30, 45, 125);
Console.WriteLine("Date with micro and milliseconds: {0:MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss.fff.ffffff}",dates);
```